# Nested Relationship in Django Doesn't Work

Tags: python, django

These are my models here:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class EndDevice(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("edevID", "siteID")

    edevID = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    siteID = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='endDeviceList', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deviceCategory = models.BigIntegerField()
```

This is my serilaizer:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EndDevice
        fields = ("edevID", "siteID", "deviceCategory")
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    endDeviceList = DeviceSerializer(many = True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ("siteID", "endDeviceList")
```

This is my view:

```
class IndividualSite(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''
    PUT site/{siteID}/
    GET site/{siteID}/
    DELETE site/{siteID}/
    '''
    queryset = EndDevice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
```

I am trying to get/put/delete results using this class and I am trying to get all the EndDevice instances which have same siteID. But my serialzer only shows the siteID and doesn't show the endDeviceList (which should have the instants of the model EndDevice)

The problem is quite similar to this link:[django rest-farmework nested relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521129/django-rest-farmework-nested-relationships).

I have been trying different ways to serialize the objects, I think this is probably the smartest way, but have been really unsucccessful. Any help will be appreciated.
The urls.py:
urlpatterns = [

```
urlpatterns = [path('site/<str:pk>/', IndividualSite.as_view(), name = "get-site"),]
```

And it is connected to the main urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `read_only` field for the `Foreign` relationship, remove that, as read_only wont display them

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    endDeviceList = DeviceSerializer(many = True)
```

Comment: I tried this, the delete and get works but put doesn't work. It says detail not found. And since it is RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView the put shuld work?

Comment: if you are trying from browser I guess put wont work, you should try post in that case

Comment: I have updated the question here, since it is RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView I think I don't need to define put separately?

Comment: did you tried with some other id as you said you have deleted one. so that cant be updated. else can you show your urls.py

Comment: Yes, I tried with different urls and I also have added the url

Comment: i dont think put will give you an error of detail not found unless the id you are passing doesnt exist in the database, else everything is ok from this side. I would suggest go to the database and check the table, get a site id which exist in the table and the try PUT method for that again

Comment: Ok. I will try that and do you think it would be a good idea to write my own put?

Comment: yes you can, but if you have other logic to implement, else no.

Comment: Do I need to give a separate definition in the serializer for update? Because there is a definition only for create there and not update

Comment: The update only works after you add a def update() in the serializer